# Typescript - Record<keyof T, string> has values of type unknown

Tags: typescript

Having this code

```js
function someMethod<T>(map: Record<keyof T, string>) {
  const values = Object.values(map)
}
```

Why `values` in defined method is of type `unknown[]`.

Why isn't the type infered from `Record's` value?

Comment: So you have a `Record<keyof T, string>`, but what is `T` in this case?

Comment: `T` looks pretty useless here without the context. But you can fix the error by adding a constraint to `T`: `T extends Record<string, unknown>`. Does that work for you?

Comment: This is how `Object.values` is typed - regardless of the context, it returns `unknown[]`. Could be explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44586).

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it is an expected behaviour. Best you can do is

```js
const values = Object.values<Something>(map)
```